# /usr/bin/c++ is not able to compile a simple test program (clang LLVM compiler): ROS2 Build from source on Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2 Win10

Tags: clang++, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2, libc++, ros2

I'm trying to install ROS2 on WSL2/Win10 Ubuntu 20.04, in order to work with Nvidia-Isaac afterwards. A colleague of mine works on 22.04 and he suggested that is was more compatible with another library which we work with, however Ubuntu 20.04 is the requirement for Nvidia-isaac.

I found that the distro "humble" is supported and tried to go on the deb packages, however it seems only one of them is present: ros-dev-tools installed, but:
ros-humble-desktop
ros-base
are not found in the repository etc. and it seems the support is only for building from source, "Tier 3".

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html

There were errors with installing part of the flake-8 libs, but reinstalling importlib_metadata resolved it.

"rosdep update" installed OK.

However then when starting the compilation: `"/usr/bin/c++ is not able to compile a simple test program "...`

```
/usr/bin/c++ --help
```

says: "OVERVIEW: clang LLVM compiler"

It seems it's the newest version.

UPDATE 17.6.2023: It seems it's related to broken libc++ packages, unfixable for now, I'll try to remove them one-by-one:

When trying to reinstall libc++, a big list of conflicts, one of them:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
> been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
> resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libc++-10-dev :
> Conflicts: libc++-x.y-dev  libc++-11-dev : Conflicts: libc++-x.y-dev
> libc++-12-dev : Conflicts: libc++-x.y-dev  libc++-14-dev : Depends:
> libunwind-14-dev but it is not going to be installed
> Conflicts: libc++-x.y-dev

I managed to remove libc++, clang, llvm (sudo apt remove ...) and for now it started building with warnings. Let's see the end result.

[image]

```
" /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
        c++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

colcon build --symlink-install
Starting >>> ament_package
Starting >>> ament_lint
Starting >>> gtest_vendor
Starting >>> fastcdr
Finished <<< gtest_vendor [1.45s]
Starting >>> gmock_vendor
--- stderr: fastcdr
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:53 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/bin/c++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/tosh/ros2-src/build/fastcdr/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_d18c1/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_d18c1.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_d18c1.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/tosh/ros2-src/build/fastcdr/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d18c1.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /usr/bin/c++     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_d18c1.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/tosh/ros2-src/build/fastcdr/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    Linking CXX executable cmTC_d18c1
    /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_d18c1.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/c++       -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_d18c1.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTC_d18c1
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
    c++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_d18c1.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_d18c1] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tosh/ros2-src/build/fastcdr/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_d18c1/fast] Error 2


 

     CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:84 (project)
    
    
    ---
    Failed   <<< fastcdr [1.84s, exited with code 1]
    Aborted  <<< gmock_vendor [0.45s]
    Aborted  <<< ament_package [2.29s]
    Aborted  <<< ament_lint [2.34s]
    
    Summary: 1 package finished [4.65s]
      1 package failed: fastcdr
      3 packages aborted: ament_lint ament_package gmock_vendor
      1 package had stderr output: fastcdr
      338 packages not processed
```

I am not sure about this part of the instruction:

> If you have already installed ROS 2 another way (either via Debians or
> the binary distribution), make sure that you run the below commands in
> a fresh environment that does not have those other installations
> sourced. Also ensure that you do not have source
> /opt/ros/${ROS_DISTRO}/setup.bash in your .bashrc. You can make sure
> that ROS 2 is not sourced with the command printenv | grep -i ROS. The
> output should be empty.

I tried to install it the other ways, but the attempts were incomplete.
Also I don't have such directory "/opt/ros/", neither .bashrc.

Suggestions? Thanks.

```
sudo apt-get install clang
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
clang is already the newest version (1:17.0-58~exp1~20230129223711.13).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apg apport-symptoms aptdaemon-data avahi-utils cheese-common coinor-libcbc3 coinor-libcgl1 coinor-libclp1
  coinor-libcoinmp1v5 coinor-libcoinutils3v5 coinor-libosi1v5 cracklib-runtime cups-pk-helper gir1.2-keybinder-3.0
  gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-secret-1 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center-faces
  gnome-online-accounts gnome-terminal-data gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 ibus-data ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 im-config ippusbxd
  libapache-pom-java libappindicator3-1 libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common
  libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcogl-common libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20
  libcolord-gtk1 libcommons-logging-java libcommons-parent-java libcrack2 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4
  libfwupdplugin1 libgail-common libgail18 libgee-0.8-2 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgpgmepp6 libgsound0 libgssdp-1.2-0
  libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgtop-2.0-11 libgtop2-common libgupnp-1.2-0 libgupnp-av-1.0-2
  libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libjuh-java libjurt-java libkeybinder-3.0-0 libldb2 liblldb-14 liblldb-15 liblldb-16
  libmediaart-2.0-0 libmwaw-0.3-3 libnautilus-extension1a libneon27-gnutls liborcus-0.15-0 libpwquality-common
  libpwquality1 libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libreoffice-style-tango libridl-java librygel-core-2.6-2
  librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2 libsbc1 libsmbclient libtalloc2 libtevent0
  libunoil-java libvte-2.91-0 libvte-2.91-common libwbclient0 libwhoopsie-preferences0 libwhoopsie0 libwps-0.4-4
  libxmlb1 libxmlsec1-nss llvm-10-runtime llvm-10-tools llvm-14-runtime llvm-14-tools mobile-broadband-provider-info
  mousetweaks network-manager-gnome pulseaudio-module-bluetooth python-cairo python-gi python3-cups
  python3-cupshelpers python3-defer python3-ldb python3-lldb-15 python3-macaroonbakery python3-protobuf
  python3-rfc3339 python3-systemd python3-talloc python3-tz python3.10-lib2to3 python3.10-minimal rygel samba-libs
  system-config-printer-udev whoopsie-preferences
```